# Jmeter Standalone Web server

Tags: jmeter

I am new to jmeter. I am trying to setup jmeter to records test using a standalone webserver. So essentially we have a standalone webserver which you can install on any machine and it automatically becomes the web server and connect to a database etc for our product. So if I have it running on my machine I use the localhost:80/clockwise and in I go to our web application. I have tried using http proxy server in workbench and adding a recording controller and thread group to test plan and it picks up say a google.com no problem and records the request and responses but not our standalone webserver it does not  pick up anything actions I perform our our web application. Is there any configuration I could use so that we can record requests/responses for our standalone web server?

Thanks

Comment: Some browsers will ignore proxy settings for localhost. Can you confirm what browser version and OS you're using?

Comment: Hi, i am using firefox and my webserver standalone application use port80. Hope this make sense

Comment: I just checked locally and and it works fine for me with JMeter 2.9 and firefox on OS X.
1. What port is JMeter proxy using?
2. Can you change the port of the local webserver to 80?
3. Can you try with different Browsers?

Comment: Hi, I am using port 8080 using HTTP proxy server. The port that the standalone webserver. exe uses is port 80. So the  webserver is listening to port80 and jmeter is listening to port 8080. I am very new to jmeter to just wondering how I can record steps for our web application. If I just browse google no problem and the setps are recorded. Can you think of anything else

Answer (score 0):

Another alternative is to use the JMeter Chrome extension instead of JMeter proxy to record the requests.

Download:
https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/blazemeter-the-load-testi/mbopgmdnpcbohhpnfglgohlbhfongabi?hl=en

Instructions:
http://community.blazemeter.com/knowledgebase/articles/231479-chrome-extension